# Camera chip identification, 12-pin, SMD, HBCZ 60X

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, cmos

May I ask for your knowledge and take a look at this image of a IC. I found this in a cmos camera that spits out a low latency <10ms video UDP stream.

I think this IC is responsible for reading a MIPI/LVDS signal and converting it to a h.256 video UDP stream of 1260x960 @30Hz.

I do not recognise this IC nor the Logo on it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dennis, you might get a faster response (and your question would be more useful to others) if you give additional information in the title. e.g., "Camera chip identification, 12-pin, SMD, HBCZ 60X". There's an [edit] link below your question.

Comment: The symbol bears some similarities to VLSI Tech's logo, who produces custom ICs. What is the name of the appliance this came in, and what is the grey stuff covering the chip and inductor?